# Tracking down a NullPointerException

Tags: java

I need to save data to MySQL database. Problem is that I have a lot of new data every second and need to filter it so I would save only necessary data. So, when I get new data, I create an object and call method processData. For some reason, this is not working. This is my method:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.llrp.ltk.types.UnsignedShort;
import hr.fer.rfid.MySQLAccess;
public class Brain {
    Data[] datas = new Data[]();
    Data[] temps = new Data[]();
    public void processValues(Data dat){

       if(temps==null){
           datas[0]=dat;
           temps[0]=dat;
       }
       for (i=0;i<(temps.length+1);i++){
          System.out.println("Process value: "+i);
          if(i==(temps.length+1)){
             temps[i]=dat;
             datas[datas.length+1]=dat;
          }
          if(i<=temps.length) {
           if(dat.epc==temps[i].epc)
              if((dat.antenna!=temps[i].antenna)
                ||((dat.date.getTime()-temps[i].date.getTime()>=5000)
                  &&(dat.date.getTime()-temps[i].date.getTime()<=20000))) {
                  temps[i]=dat;
                  try {

                   dao.writeToDatabase(dat);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

I get `NullPointerException`

Comment: NPE?  Really?  This isn't even close to compiling - how on earth did you run it?

Comment: This is only part of code. You need MySQLAccess class and Object Data. I think the problem is this line: for (i=0;i<(temps.length+1);i++){

Comment: Might want to point where you get your npe. Or even better, attach you stacktrace as well.

Comment: An exception always goes with its stacktrace, which tells you all the required information. Learn that rule as "rule number one".

Comment: Seems like you didnt declare 'dao'

Comment: Sorry, but it only says An error occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: that's not a stacktrace. That's a fully-qualified name.

Comment: Bozho, that is all that is printed in console, where can I find more info?

Comment: Check through the rest of your code and make sure you are not catching the NPE somewhere else and doing something like `System.out.println(e);`. Stack traces are automatically generated if the exception is uncaught, so there must be code somewhere catching either `NullPointerException`, `RuntimeException` or `Exception`, all of which are poor practice for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 2):

At least this compiles now.  Note the changes around the declaration of the Data arrays.  If the arrays aren't dynamic enough for you, I'd recommend using `List<Data>` instead.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Brain {

    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;
    Data[] datas = new Data[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    Data[] temps = new Data[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    Dao dao = new Dao();

    public void processValues(Data dat){

       if(temps==null){
           datas[0]=dat;
           temps[0]=dat;
       }
       for (int i=0;i<(temps.length+1);i++){
          System.out.println("Process value: "+i);
          if(i==(temps.length+1)){
             temps[i]=dat;
             datas[datas.length+1]=dat;
          }
          if(i<=temps.length) {
           if(dat.epc==temps[i].epc)
              if((dat.antenna!=temps[i].antenna)
                ||((dat.date.getTime()-temps[i].date.getTime()>=5000)
                  &&(dat.date.getTime()-temps[i].date.getTime()<=20000))) {
                  temps[i]=dat;
                  try {

                   dao.writeToDatabase(dat);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    }
 }

class Data
{
    public String epc;
    public Date date;
    public String antenna;
}

class Dao
{
    public void writeToDatabase(Data data)  {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that doesn't solve the problem, I iterate plus one so I can add new temp if it is not already listed.

Comment: I made several changes, including a declaration of Dao.  Your code isn't good; I'd rework this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in your code, so here's the first one:

```
if(temps==null){
    datas[0]=dat;
    temps[0]=dat;
}
```

Guaranteed NullPointerException if `temps` is null.

You are also not checking that `dat` is non-null, nor does your code show that you have initialised `dao`.

Not related to the NPE, but this is a logic error:

```
for (i=0;i<(temps.length+1);i++){
    System.out.println("Process value: "+i);
    if(i==(temps.length+1)) {
        ...
    }
```

`i` can never be `temps.length + 1` because the loop condition is that `i < temps.length + 1`.

There are other problems here too numerous to mention. I highly recommend that you use some static analysis tools (such as [Checkstyle](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)) to help improve your code quality. These are good, open-source tools that can pick up common mistakes before they turn into bugs. I use them all the time and they have improved my coding standards immensely.

Comment: thanks for the answer, dao is initialised, that is not a problem... dat is always non null, but I'll cover that... I don't understand why is this guaranteed NPE? If it is null I put an object inside and it shouldn't be null anymore and should be able to iterate...

Comment: It's guaranteed because you say "if temps is null then do something to temps". If it is null then the array *does not exist*, so trying to set the first element will result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: if it's a null, then it's not initialized. you can't put an object inside of something that is not initialized. it would be the same as if you would try to put an apple in a basket, but the basket doesn't exist.